# Does Go have a feature to automatically export unexported names?

Tags: go

I'm getting hundreds of errors like:

> foo.thing undefined (type Foo has no field or method thing, but does have Thing)

i.e. the fix is very simple, just change `foo.thing` to `foo.Thing`.

Is there a way in Go to tell `go build` to just go ahead and make these changes in mass?

Comment: First, how did you start getting these hundreds of errors? If you are using someone else's code, did you set it up incorrectly?

Comment: The `go` command does not have that feature.  Perhaps your editor has the feature to export an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

The [GoLand refactoring "Rename a code element﻿"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/rename-refactorings.html#invoke-rename-refactoring) might be a good approach.

[image]

VSCode [rename symbol](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#_rename-symbol) could help too.

But Go itself does not have that.
There is a backlog feature request for the compilation error message to be more precise ([issue 38965](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/38965))

Instead of (in [this example](https://play.golang.org/p/CRyflGpyRyg))

```sh
./prog.go:11:7: a.B undefined (type A has no field or method B, but does have b)
./prog.go:12:3: a.s undefined (type A has no field or method s, but does have S)
```

Having the more prescriptive:

```sh
./prog.go:11:7: a.B undefined (type A has no field or method B, but does have field b)
./prog.go:12:3: a.s undefined (type A has no field or method s, but does have method S)
```

[CL 232938](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/232938/), May 2020, still pending.